# How to add a set on numbers on a two dimensional array based on the results of first row in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array:

```
var array = [["Alex", 10], ["Sam", 15], ["Alex", 20], ["Rob", 20], ["Sam", 10]];
```

How can I make a new array where in the result would be something like this.

```
newArray = [["Alex", 30], ["Sam", 25], ["Rob", 20]];
```

So basically what I want is to get the sum of the numbers for a particular individual.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know if I have been able to explain the problem properly.

Comment: I took some editorial license and put the last Sam's `10` inside that array element, since it looked like a typo. Please revert it if I was incorrect.

Comment: thanks for the edit. it was indeed a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the original data source to edit the structure?
Converting it in to an Array of Objects like this would be much neater and easier to deal with:

```
var array = [
    {name: "Alex", age: 10}, 
    {name: "Sam", age: 15}, 
    {name: "Alex", age: 20}, 
    {name: "Rob", age: 20},
    {name: "Sam", age: 10},
];
```

then you could use an [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) inside an [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to extract the uniques like so:

```
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(person => {
    if (newArray.filter(item => item.name === person.name).length < 1) newArray.push(person);
});
```

Super clean and utilises the [ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and shorthand :D

**NOTE:** If you can't change the original data source, you could re-format the data before the forEach using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
array.map(item => {name: item[0], age: item[1]});
```

This will manipulate the original Array, replacing all entries with their Object equivalent.

**NOTE #2:** If you need legacy support, replacing the arrow functions with their anonymous function older brother e.g. `function(item) { return {name: item[0], age: item[1]} }` will make this code supported down to IE 9

Comment: Thanks a lot George! Converting it to an array object seems much easier. And yes, I do have an access to the original data.

Comment: Hey Sayan, that's great news! glad i could help. Please accept this answer as the solution if it's the one you used :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and associate each array to the name in it. In case of repeated name, add its numeric value. After that, get the result using `Object.values()`

```js
var array = [["Alex", 10], ["Sam", 15], ["Alex", 20], ["Rob", 20], ["Sam", 10]];

var result = array.reduce((res,[name,val]) => {
  if(name in res)
    res[name][1] += val;
  else
    res[name] = [name,val];
  return res;
},Object.create(null));

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hasan for the easy solution. I was writing tons of codes for this result.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for same name reference and update the value if a hash exists.

```js
var array = [["Alex", 10], ["Sam", 15], ["Alex", 20], ["Rob", 20], ["Sam", 10]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!hash[a[0]]) {
            hash[a[0]] = a;
            r.push(a);
            return r;
        }
        hash[a[0]][1] += a[1];
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a lookup hash object:

```
const result = [], hash = {};

for(const [name, val] of array){
  if( hash[name] ) {
    hash[name][1] += val;
  } else {
    result.push( hash[name] = [name, val] );
  }
}
```